# Separar os métodos estáticos em várias classes pode ter um impacto negativo?

Tags: c#, .net, classes, desempenho, métodos-estáticos

Em questão de organização é relevante separar os métodos em classes diferentes.

Se organizarmos os métodos em classes diferentes no fim de criar uma organização melhor, podemos ter um impacto negativo no desempenho do programa?

Por exemplo, eu tenho um aplicativo onde vários métodos estão em uma classe só, se eu criar novas classes para abrigar categorias específicas de métodos, posso ter um impacto negativo?

Comment: É um pouco vago avaliar esses impactos sem saber qual é a função do seu código, O interessante é conhecer muito bem os Padrões de Projeto (Design Patterns) para escolher o que melhor lhe atende. Todas escolhas também são renuncias. Pesquise um pouco sobre assunto:
https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padr%C3%A3o_de_projeto_de_software#Padr.C3.B5es_GoF_.28.27Gang_of_Four.27.29.3B

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nenhum impacto de desempenho só porque fez isso. Pode haver se fizer alguma outra coisa ruim, mas seria indireto.

Mesmo que tivesse alguma perda seria insignificante. E a organização deve vir em primeiro lugar. A preocupação com desempenho só se houver motivo e o ganho for interessante.

Em geral as classes devem ter responsabilidade única, então separar se fizer sentido é o que deve fazer.

Answer (score 1):

Apenas como complemento, há uma diferença negativa(mas realmente leve) na memória do processo do aplicativo, que, ao menos pra mim, vale o preço da organização do código.

A diferença de desempenho existe mas nem chega a ser perceptível, ao menos não nos computadores de hoje, acredito que talvez seja perceptível em dispositivos com menos capacidade, mas apenas teoricamente.

Em conclusão, vale a pena organizar seu código, mas lembre-se que organizar não é apenas dividir em várias classes, faça algo compacto e bonito ao invés de dividir mais do que deve, mesmo que tenha uma diferença pouco relevante, se você pode fazer algo do melhor modo, porquê não?

Comment: Que diferença seria esta?